# My sugar daddy is threatening to get me in trouble because he has my ssn and all my personal information is this even possible if so what do I do

Tags: bank-account, social-security, sugar-daddy

We exchanged phone numbers and all personal information and If I don’t give him what he wants he said he could get me in major trouble what do I do I can’t keep doing this? How do I know if this is real

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'all personal information"? Date of birth? Bank account numbers? passwords?

Answer (score 0):

He is blackmailing you, or attempting to blackmail you. If you do anything he wants you to do, he will ask you to do more.

So what you do is first go to the police (whatever he tries to do will be less harmful if you can show you went to the police). You don’t do *anything* he wants you to do, under no circumstances. You then have the choice to either tell him to go f*** himself, or maybe safer to promise everything he wants and of course do nothing. Always tell him that you will do it at the next possible opportunity with some new excuse. NEVER do what he asks you to.

In the future, don’t give your SSN or personal information to anyone. And remember that *nobody* gives you money for free unless you do this professionally and are very clever.